# How to set color of Chart.js tick label based on tick value - negative values red

Tags: chart.js

I would like to set the color of y-axis tick labels in Chart.js bar and line charts based on the numeric label value. Specifically, I'd like negative values to be rendered red.  Additionally rather than displaying "-1", "-2", etc., I'd like to override to display "(1)", "(2)", etc.

I've seen examples for changing tick labels based on index / position, but not conditionally based on the label value.  Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the scriptable option `scales.x.ticks.color` as an array of colors that depend on the corresponding data value each. The following definition for example shows red tick labels for every bar of a value less than 10.

```
scales: {
  x: {
    ticks: {
      color: data.map(v => v < 10 ? 'red' : undefined)
    }
  }
}
```

> For further information, consult [Tick Configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#tick-configuration) from the Chart.js documentation.

Please take a look at below runnable code and see how it works.

```js
const data = [4, 12, 5, 13, 15, 8];

new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Dataset',
      data: data,
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: false,
    scales: {
      x: {
        ticks: {
          color: data.map(v => v < 10 ? 'red' : undefined)
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="180"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution.  That's an interesting and effective way to set tick color based on the data associated with the bar, in this particular case.  I will definitely use this technique in a similar circumstance.

Comment: In my case, I wanted to set the tick color, as well as change formatting, based on the sign of the tick value computed by chart.js, independent of any data point value.  In the case of a multiple series line chart I can't associate a tick value with a particular data set.  The solution for this case that I landed on is to add  color: (c) => { if(c[tick']['value'] < 0) return 'red' }.  Thanks again.